# Can't upgrade database version

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

It tells me that my database version must be `0 >= 1`  and if I put `1` it tells me that it can't upgrade it from `0` to `1`.

`myDB` constructor:

```
public database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_Version);   // DB_Version doesn't work if it is 0 or 1
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

An instance is created like this from another class:

```
dbClass = new database(this);
```

Comment: tried using number greater than 1?

Comment: Then try using greater than 1...It works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the db and recreate with `version = 1` initially.

Comment: I did so and it said it can upgrade form version 0 to version 1

Comment: What is the exact error message? Does it say: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from..."?

Comment: ok, which line of the code that causes this error? can you post it.